Mount ZFS encrypted dataset to be available for only one user
In Ubuntu 22.04, I've created an encrypted dataset hdd/enc and for privacy reasons I need it to be available only for me. Every time the system gets rebooted, it's ok for me to enter the password I never store anywhere manually by mount -a -l and entering the passphrase. But since others may ssh to my system and view their files and have sudo privilege and even have root password of my system because of the company's policies, they may view my private files too. I was using encfs, but I think it's a better idea to use the builtin capabilities of zfs instead. The encfs limits access of others even root to the folder I encrypt. I need to know whether the zfs encryption also has this ability?

"The encfs limits access of others even root to the folder I encrypt" – Because it uses FUSE that by design gives permission denied even to root (example). There is zfs-fuse but I don't know if it's an answer here.

I think I'm using zfs-fuse already, although I'm not sure. How can I make sure? Anyway, I don't think this is the cause.
